# Problema de declaração de variável para compilar no Code::Blocks

Tags: c, declaração-de-variável, codeblocks, mingw

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>

int main () {

    setlocale (LC_ALL,"Portuguese");

    int num,escolha; char nome[20];

    printf ("\nDigite seu nome: ");
    gets (nome);

    printf ("\nInforme um número: ");
    scanf ("%d",&num);

    printf ("\nDigite 1 para ver os números pares ou 2 para ver os números ímpares: ");
    scanf ("%i",&escolha);

    switch (escolha){
        case 1: for (int i = 0; i < num; i ++){
                    if (i%2==0){
                        printf ("\n%i",i); } }
        break;

        case 2: for (int h = 0; h < num; h ++){
                    if (h%2==1){
                        printf ("\n%i",h); } }
        break;

        default: printf ("\nOpção invalida.");
    }

    num % 2==0 ? printf("\n\n%s o número digitado por você é par !\n\a",nome) : printf("\n\n%s o número digitado por você é ímpar !\n\a",nome);

    getchar ();

    return 0;
}
```

Alguém sabe me informar por que esse código compila no dev, mas no blocks ele da esse erro ( ps já aconteceu com vários códigos essa parada de não compilar e uso ele por que como eu li no cprogressivo.net ele tem bem mais vantagens que os outros ) :

[image: Antes de reclamar a imagem está em png !]

O compilador : mingw

[image: Do code::blocks]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No Code Blocks vá em: `Project -> Build Options -> Compiler Settings -> Other Options` aí coloca o `-std=99` ou `std=c11`, conforme o próprio compilador lhe instruiu.

Portanto era só seguir as instruções dadas e "fuçar" no IDE. Não precisava pesquisar nada, muito menos assistir vídeos, eles não costumam ensinar ninguém programar.

Pode ser que outros erros apareçam, por exemplo, pode haver uma indicação para não usar `gets()`. Mesmo que não apareça, é bom conselho. Outro bom conselho é organizar melhor o código. É difícil dizer o que ele faz mesmo sendo um exemplo simples, imagine quando fizer coisas maiores. Mantenha um padrão, coloque em linhas novas blocos novos. Tem hora que espaça demais, tem hora que economiza no espaçamento. Embora eu goste do operador condicional, ele não deve ser usado sempre que tem um `if`. Curiosamente neste caso ele até poderia ser usado, mas dentro do `printf()`, não como escolha de qual deles executar.

Comment: Eu coloquei tudo em ordem, o código está com a identação ok, só faltou os comentários então o que estou fazendo errado ? ( valeu não vou usar gets ! )